# typescript/express error handling middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript

hi i have this middlware for handle errors on my project:

```
  private initializeErrorHandling() {
    this.app.use(
      (err: Error, request: Request, response: Response, _: NextFunction) => {
        if (err instanceof CustomExternalError) {
          return response.status(err.statusCode).json(err.message);
        }

        console.log(err);

        return response.status(500).json({
          status: 'error',
          message: 'Internal server error',
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

I use the following controller structure:

```
@singleton()
export class DepartamentController implements IController {
  private router: Router;
  private path: string;
  private services: DepartamentServices;
  constructor() {
    this.path = '/departament';
    this.router = Router();
    this.services = container.resolve(DepartamentServices);
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }
  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/create`, this.test.bind(this));
  }
  getPath(): string {
    return this.path;
  }
  getRouter(): Router {
    return this.router;
  }

  private async test() {
    this.services.test();
  }

}
```

and this is my role in my service where I invoke my error:

```
 public async test() {
    throw new CustomExternalError(
      {
        message: 'Validation Failed',
        errors: [
          {
            resource: 'Departament',
            field: 'a',
            code: 'unprocessable',
          },
        ],
      },
      responseCodes.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
    );
  }
```

this is my custom error:

```
export class CustomExternalError {
  constructor(public error: responseError, public statusCode: responseCodes) {
    this.error;
    this.statusCode;
  }
}
```

and I add my routes to my express server with the following function:

```
  private initializeRoutes() {
    container.resolveAll<IController>('Controller').forEach(controller => {
      this.app.use('/', controller.getRouter());
    });
  }
```

My route works normally, but for some reason when throwing the error it doesn't call my middlware error handle, but if I call the error on my controller it works normally

i got this error :

```
(node:8704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<CustomExternalError>
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8704) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: This comment might be unhelpful as I am no expert in express, but `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is normally happening when a promise throws/rejects, and you do not have a `.catch`-statement. Not sure if the framework should do this for you, but perhaps returning the promise produced by the `test`-method will help you out? When you `throw` inside an `async` method, it becomes a failing promise, so not handling it's error creates a new error. In other words, perhaps `return this.services.test();` in `DepartamentController#test` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `test` method is async, so when it throws anything it needs to be handled inside that promise's `catch` block otherwise you'll have that promise rejection warning. So, you may want to create a middleware that catch those unhandled promise rejections and pass them to your errors handler middleware:

You can either use a wrapper method that handles that:

```
const asynchHandler = fn => (...args) => fn(args).catch(args[2])
```

or this package: [express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler).

Then in your controller:

```
  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/create`, asynchHandler(this.test.bind(this)));
  }
```

Or just handle your promise rejection and explicitly call the `midleware`

```
private async test(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  try {
     ...
     await this.service.test(...)
     ...
   } catch (err: CustomExternalError) {
     next(next)
   }
 }
```